# Text Compression and Decompression using BWT

Tags: java, compression, burrows-wheeler-transform

I want to ask that can we combine the BWT MTF and Huffman Algorithms to get higher compression rate in java? what will be the process?
Error In Wriring of MTF file?

```
public class MTF{
    static File f=new File("MTF.txt");
public static File encode(String msg, String symTable)throws Exception{
            if(!f.exists())
                f.createNewFile();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(symTable);
    for(char c : msg.toCharArray()){
        int idx = s.indexOf("" + c);
                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f); 
                    writer.write(idx+" "); 
                    System.out.print(idx+" ");
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
        s = s.deleteCharAt(idx).insert(0, c);
    }
            System.out.println("MTF done");
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Higher than what? By the way this is approximately what bzip2 does

Comment: higher than simple huffman compression.. and i need to implement it my self

Comment: Definitely better than simple Huffman compression, since BWT + MTF effectively gives a contextual prediction based on the right-context of a symbol.

Comment: i tried BWT than MTF and than Huffman but the file get double in size... when i removed the mtf from the middle it compresses 7%.. What can be the reason?

Comment: Can you find a *really small* file that makes that happen and post it, its BWT, the MTF'd data, and the lengths of the Huffman codes?

Comment: MTF is fine, but then the Huffman codes should be mapping those integers to codes but it's mapping mysterious characters to codes

Comment: I did huffman on BWT not MTF

Comment: Quick Question Huffman uses characters to map codes.. but the MTF contains integers like 23,18,23. What should i do there?

Comment: If you do the Huffman coding on the bare BWT, then the MTF is not used at all, that would be very strange. And the input for Huffman coding can be any finite set of things, doesn't matter whether it's characters or integers, the "meaning" is never used only the frequencies.

Comment: @harold check for error in code!

Comment: I don't think there is an error exactly, but having the MTF'd file *as text* is only useful for debugging. What I mean is, what you should be Huffman encoding is data like `[20, 0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 2, 0, 0, 2]` etc. Not a string "20 0 0 0 1 10 2 0 0 2".

Comment: I am using STringTokenizer to make an array of integers for Huffman

Comment: OK sounds reasonable (though slow). What are your Huffman codes like now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy to test this hypothesis, the process would be:

- take a representative set of strings (strings that your program will be dealing with in "real world");
- encode with BWT MTF (implementations are numerous on the internet);
- compress with Huffman;

**In general**: Applying MTF should improve compresability, as, for example mentioned here: http://michael.dipperstein.com/bwt/

> BWT is useful because it converts the data into a format that is
>   generally more compressible by run length encoders and statistical
>   encoders with order greater than 0. By additionally applying
>   move-to-front coding, the data will be in a format which is generally
>   more compressible by even zero order statistical encoders such as
>   traditional implementations of Huffman coding or arithmetic coding.